# java.lang.exception microsoft-translator-api Error retreiving translation: permission denied (missing internet permission?)

Tags: android, permissions, runtime, microsoft-translator

Hi All i am new to Android and trying to build an English to German translator and i am getting the above error when i run this app on the mobile screen.

package com.exmaple.android.lang_trans;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;

import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.TextView;

import com.exmaple.android.lang_trans.R;

import com.memetix.mst.language.Language;

import com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener {

```
private TextToSpeech tts;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.bSpeak)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            speakOut(((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTranslatedText)).getText().toString());
        }
    });

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.bTranslate)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            class bgStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try {
                        if (params.length > 0) {
                            return translate(params[0]);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return e.toString();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTranslatedText)).setText(result);
                }
            }

            new bgStuff().execute(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserText)).getText().toString());
        }
    });
}

public String translate(String text) throws Exception {


    // Set the Client ID / Client Secret once per JVM. It is set statically and applies to all services
    Translate.setClientId("CLIENT ID"); //Change this
    Translate.setClientSecret("CLIENT SECRET"); //change


    String translatedText = "";

    translatedText = Translate.execute(text, Language.GERMAN);

    return translatedText;
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.GERMAN);

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
        } else {

            //speakOut("Ich");
        }

    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
    }
}

private void speakOut(String text) {
    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you didn't request permission to access the internet 
in your manifest you should add this line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

under the `<manifest` block